# Calculates the average score group

Tags: c

I have an array, where each element it's notation about students:

```
group number | name | evaluations
---------------------------------
4272 Галкин Г. А. 5445
4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333
4273 Курочкин А. А. 3433
4272 Козлов И. И. 4443
```

I need to calculate the average score of each group, namely to obtain in this case two numbers:

- `(5 + 4 + 4 + 5) + (4 + 4 + 4 + 3) = 33 / 2 = 16.5`
- `(4 + 3 + 3 + 3) + (3 + 4 + 3 + 3) = 26 / 2 = 13`

So, in output should I get: `4272 -- 16.5` and `4273 -- 13`. Tell me, please, how I can do it.

My function currently looks like:

```
void group_average_scope() {
  char name[50];
  int group;
  int exam;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int sum_of_evaluations = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int counter_digits = 0;

    sscanf(student_list[i], "%d %[^0-9] %d", &group, name, &exam);

    while (exam > 0) {
      digit = exam % 10;
      sum_of_evaluations += digit;
      counter_digits++;
      exam = exam / 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't pay any attention to group, while your problem statement does.  You need to keep an average for each group, which means you have to track your sum and counter for each group that is input.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein yes, of course, I asked about it. I don't understand how I can track sum and group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this. (This code is pseudo-code.)

```
#define GROUP_NUM 5000
typedef struct list{
    int group;
    int number_of_students;
    int sum_of_eval;
    list(){group = 0; number_of_students = 0; sum_of_eval = 0;};
};
```

Until here, I made a structure to save information for a group, the number of students and sum of evaluations in that group.

```
char name[50];
  int group;
  int exam;
  list students_group[GROUP_NUM];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int sum_of_evaluations = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int counter_digits = 0;
    sscanf(student_list[i], "%d %[^0-9] %d", &group, name, &exam);

    printf("%d %s %d\n",group,name,exam);//test

    while (exam > 0) {
      digit = exam % 10;
      sum_of_evaluations += digit;
      counter_digits++;
      exam = exam / 10;
    }
    students_group[group].group = group;
    students_group[group].number_of_students++;
    students_group[group].sum_of_eval += sum_of_evaluations;
  }
  for( group = 0 ; group < GROUP_NUM; group++){
    if(students_group[group].group > 0){
        printf("%d -- %g\n",students_group[group].group ,
               (double)students_group[group].sum_of_eval / students_group[group].number_of_students);
    }
  }
```

I don't know about information of 'group'. so I assume that 'group' exist 0 to 4999.
And just print average in this function.
 If you want to save average value, you have to receive pointer of structure.
 And if you have any doubt, mail to me.

Comment: My only complaint is that I would change `students_group[group].number_of_students++` to `students_group[group].number_of_students += counter_digits`, since that's already being used in finding the average.

Comment: Also, you don't need `group` in your struct, since it's defined as your array index.